# I have delete the entries of tables from my migration table, how can i retrive it

Tags: laravel, migration

In Laravel we have a migration file which keep the names of all table that is migrated. I have delete the all entries from the migration file. the issue is that when i refresh migration i will lost my data. i just want to rollback the entries of migration file. is it possible?

I want to rollback the all entries in migration file that i have deleted

Comment: If you have deleted data from a table/database and you do not have a backup of it (snapshot or anything similar), then bye bye data for ever

Answer (score -1):

You have only one choice now which is to enter all ran migrations in the migrations table manually.